# DBT dynamic config

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I have a generic test and need it to be always saved under a particular name for the given table it is running on, e.g. on table report_revenue the generated generic test name will always be *diff_check_report_revenue*. Right now the default dbt naming behavior for generic tests is kinda messy (it sets the test name based on the test config, which is a great idea for most cases, but unfortunately not for my particular one).
According to the docs it looks like the [alias]https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/alias is exactly what I need. However, I also need to set the name dynamically based on the table that is tested. I know it can be set in the yml config by setting the field *alias*, but I hope there might be a more elegant solution.
When I try the following:

```
{{
    config({
        "severity": 'warn',
        "tags": ["diff_check"],
        "alias": 'diff_check_' + {{ model | replace("XXXXXXX") | trim }}
    })
}}
```

It just doesn't work and dbt completely ignores the alias property. *model* is the relation on which the test is running. It's probably just my own wrong syntax, but I'm stuck and humbly asking for advice. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The docs are super confusing on test config, since they group together generic tests and singular tests, and the behavior is different.

You can use a `config()` block inside the definition for a generic test to configure it, and some keys (e.g., severity) work fine, but `alias` is not one of them.

I think `alias` is meant for singular tests only. To give generic tests a unique identifier (only possible since v1.1), you are supposed to use the `name` property (not config). [Docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-properties/tests#define-a-custom-name-for-one-test). Does this make sense? No. Does it make it easy for you to do what you want to do? Also no.

I'll point out that the *default* naming convention for a generic test includes the name of the test followed by the name of the model, but assuming that isn't good enough, your only option will be to add a `name` property to every test, where you define the test in the properties (fka `schema.yml`) file. And it looks like the `name` property doesn't jinja-template its value (so you can't use jinja to populate the test name). So you'll have to do a lot of this:

```yaml
models:
  - name: my_model
    tests:
      - diff_check:
          name: diff_check_my_model
```

You *could* fork dbt-core. The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/065ab2ebc2104635770f49ca48bc434532d3ef41/core/dbt/parser/generic_test_builders.py#L40).